# POST request on Ajax Complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do a token exchange after every `AJAX` request performed on my site.
To do this, I am currently using the `jQuery` function `.ajaxSuccess`.
My problem is, whenever I try to perform an `AJAX` request within this function, it's obviously seeing it as a success and is this creating a recurring function.

How can I make a one-time `AJAX` request situated within this function which only runs once?

I.e. like so:-

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    $.post("somewhere", {some: "data"}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Guessing you have another ajax function somewhere which causes this one to be triggered?  Move your closure to that initial function instead of the 'global' ajaxSuccess function

Comment: But then I'll have to add the function I want to happen to the end of every ajax request, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check, if you actually need to make an `AJAX` request in your [`ajaxSuccess`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/) handler like so

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    if (settings.url != "somewhere") {
        $.post("somewhere", {some: "data"}, function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Uhm, wow. Why I didn't think of this I have no idea. Cheers for this.